# How can I add Javascript to change header text color on scroll in Shopify (District Theme)

Tags: javascript, shopify

So I have this js code but it's not being applied. I want the on-scroll class to be added to .logo-nav-contain, but when I scroll nothing happens. If I apply the red background to the .logo-nav-contain class it changes, so I know the style block is right. I think it may have something to do with Shopify and JS. Does anyone see a mistake here?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
            $(".logo-nav-contain").addClass("on-scroll");
        } else {
         $(".logo-nav-contain").removeClass("on-scroll");
        }
    });
});
  
</script>

<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=397982167525776&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->


<style>
  .on-scroll {
    background-color: red !important; 
  }
 
  
</style>


<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}"  data-section-type="header-section" >
  <div class="site-header-wrapper">
    <header class="site-header {% if section.settings.minimal_padding == "minimal" %}minimal{% endif %} {% if section.settings.header_full_width %}full-width{% endif %}" data-scroll-lock="{{ section.settings.scroll_lock }}" role="banner">
      <div class="wrapper" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1000; width: 100%; padding-right: 40px">
        <div class="logo-nav-contain layout-{{ section.settings.header_layout }}">
          {% comment %}
            Use the uploaded logo from theme settings if enabled.
            Site name gets precedence with H1 tag on homepage, div on other pages.
          {% endcomment %}
          
          
          {% comment %}
           mobile menu below 
          {% endcomment %}
          <header class="util">
              <div class="wrapper">

                  <div class="left-wrapper">
                    <ul class="text-links">
                      <li class="mobile-menu">
                        <a href="#menu" class="toggle-menu menu-link">
                          <span class="icon-text">
                            <span class="icon icon-menu" aria-hidden="true">{% include 'icon-ui-menu' %}</span>
                            <span class="text" data-close-text="{{ 'layout.drawers.close_menu' | t }}">{{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t }}</span>
                          </span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          </header> 
            
          
          <div class="logo-contain">
            {% if template.name == 'index' %}
              <h1 class="site-logo {% if section.settings.logo %}has-image{% endif %}" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            {% else %}
              <div class="site-logo {% if section.settings.logo %}has-image{% endif %}" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            {% endif %}
              {% if section.settings.logo %}
                <a href="/" itemprop="url" class="logo-image">
                  {%- assign image = section.settings.logo -%}
                  {%- assign image_default_width = section.settings.logo_max_width -%}
                  {%- assign image_2x_width = image_default_width | times: 2 -%}
                  {%- assign image_3x_width = image_default_width | times: 3 -%}
                  {%- assign image_default = image_default_width | append: 'x' -%}
                  {%- capture widths -%}{{ image_default_width }},{{ image_2x_width }},{{ image_3x_width }}{%- endcapture -%}
                  {% assign image_widths = widths %}
                  {% include 'theme-rias' %}
                  <img id="{{ img_id }}" class="lazyload"
                    src="{{ image | img_url: image_default }}"
                    data-src="{{ image_url_pattern }}"
                    data-widths="[{{ image_widths }}]"
                    data-aspectratio="{{ image.aspect_ratio }}"
                    data-sizes="auto"
                    alt="{{ image.alt | escape | default: shop.name }}">
                </a>
              {% else %}
                <a href="/" itemprop="url">{{ shop.name }}</a>
              {% endif %}
            {% if template.name == 'index' %}
              </h1>
            {% else %}
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          
         
          <nav class="nav-bar" role="navigation">
            {% include 'site-nav' %}
          </nav>
          <header class="util">
            <div class= "right-wrapper">
              {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
                {% include 'accounts-nav' %}
              {% endif %}

               <a href="/cart" id="CartButton">
                 <span class="icon-fallback-text"></span>
                    {{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}
                 <span id="CartCount">({{ cart.item_count }})</span>
               </a>
               {% if settings.ajax_cart_enable %}
                {% include 'cart-preview' %}
               {% endif %}
          </div>

         </header>

          
      
        </div>

      </div>
    </header>
   </div>
</div>


<nav id="menu" class="panel" role="navigation">
 
  <div class="search">
    {% include 'search-bar' %}
  </div>
  
  {% include 'site-nav' %}

  <div class="account">
    {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
      {% include 'accounts-nav' %}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You do not see the class being added/removed on scroll?

Comment: I don't, even in the inspector.

Comment: @prettyInPink I'm not sure where the error is, or if I applied the js in the .liquid file correctly.

Comment: Can you log anything in the scroll event?

Comment: I added a console.log right above the if statement and it did not log when I scrolled

Comment: Probably a silly question, but you did include the jQuery library? Like this example: https://shopthemedetector.com/blog/how-to-add-jquery-to-shopify/ You are not seeing any errors displayed in the console either?

Comment: No I didn't! I've never added the jQuery library, I thought I could just use JS right in the .liquid file.

Comment: Javascript is not the issue, but using jQuery requires to include the library, but if you aren't seeing any errors in the console, could mean the library was included by the theme, I guess.

Comment: Could I change this to plain JS and then not need to import anything. There is a <script> tag and a <javascript> tag in this .liquid file. I'm not sure I should be putting this in the <script> tag or not.

Comment: Sure this can be written in vanilla js, using ```window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        //add your vanilla js here
});```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am new to this. So I added a few console.logs in the vanilla js function, but nothing is logging. Is there something else I need to do to use js in .liquid?

Comment: Try it using these instructions: https://www.huratips.com/tech-tips/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-shopify-theme.html

Comment: And as for ```js``` the following should work for you: ```let logo = 
document.querySelector('.logo-nav-contain');
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {

  let scrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;

  if(scrolled > 1){
    logo.classList.add(
      'on-scroll');
    }else {
    logo.classList.remove(
      'on-scroll');
    }
});```

Comment: I added an example below, so you can see the code working.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let logo = document.querySelector('.logo-nav-contain');
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {

  let scrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;

  if(scrolled > 1){
    logo.classList.add(
      'on-scroll');
    }else {
    logo.classList.remove(
      'on-scroll');
    }
});
```

```css
.logo-nav-contain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.on-scroll {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-nav-contain">logo</div>
<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```